# Extensions of flat modules and tensor products

Tags: ring-theory, flatness

Let $R$ be a ring and let
$$0 \rightarrow M_1 \rightarrow M_2 \rightarrow M_3 \rightarrow 0$$
be a short exact sequence of flat $R$-modules.  Let $N$ be another $R$-module.  Question: is the sequence
$$0 \rightarrow M_1 \otimes_R N \rightarrow M_2 \otimes_R N \rightarrow M_3 \otimes_R N \rightarrow 0$$
necessarily exact?  If we assumed that $N$ was flat and the $M_i$ were arbitrary, then this would be the definition of flatness, but I don't know about this other situation.

Comment: In fact, one only needs that $M_{3}$ is flat. See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HL, for instance.

Comment: The comment above is correct. For modules, we can take its presentation and form a commutative diagram of tensor products, and then Snake Lemma leads you to the end.